# Get Cannot find column [SchemaName]. when trying to add Table to imported SSAS project

Tags: ssas

After importing my SSAS project from the prod environment into visual studios, it seems that I can't add any new tables to the datasource view.

```
This is the error msg I get:
"TITLE: Microsoft Visual Studio
------------------------------

Cannot find column [SchemaName].
```

Any idea what is wrong and how i can fix it?

using SSAS 2008 and connecting to Sybase IQ 15.2.

Comment: What version of SSAS are you using and what kind of database are you connecting to in your source?

Comment: using SSAS 2008 and connecting to Sybase IQ 15.2.

Answer (score 0):

I was **able to resolve** this one but what all I understood was it is a Visual Studio bug.
I **re-installed the Visual Studio** and it worked fine. I got this idea because I was able to do the same thing, without any errors, from another server (a different system basically).

So, you can try that.

P.S. All the best.